# How can I put the various elements come from for loop in a list?

Tags: python

```
['aba']['b']['c']
```

These above element came while iterating in a loop and I want to make a list which contains these elements. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Define an empty list before your for-loop, then inside the for-loop, append the items to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an empty list and then append results to that list. For example:

```
loop = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
endresult = []
for i in loop:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        endresult.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```